# Object with readonly hashset assign values at initialization of object

Tags: c#, hashset

So apparently this works:

```
new SomeClass {
   SomeReadonlyPropertyHashSetOfStrings = { "somevalue", "somevalue2"}
}
```

with a class of:

```
class SomeClass {
    public HashSet<string> SomeReadonlyPropertyHashSetOfStrings {get; private set; } = new HashSet<string>();
}
```

Which is cool, if a little creapy.

But let's say that I have a predefined array of strings in a variable like so:

```
var someStringArray = new [] { "someValue1", "someValue2"};
```

How does one assign that to SomeReadonlyPropertyHashSetOfStrings in the initialization of the class per above but with a variable instead of direct assignment?  Just setting it = doesn't work.

And where is this voodoo documented? I can't find anything anywhere with google.

Thanks!

Comment: Google for 'Collection Initializers'.

Comment: `but with a variable instead of direct assignment?` This can be done using `var bob = new HashSet<string>(someStringArray);` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__

Comment: That doesn't work when the hashset is private set on the object.

Comment: Can you show me what you tried? Since it seems to work - https://dotnetfiddle.net/1PrZdk . If you want it to do it _outside_ of the constructor you will need to write an `AddRange` extension method and invoke that.

Comment: @mjwills your example works because you have `SomeReadonlyPropertyHashSetOfStrings` contained in the `Program` class. It won't work when it's in `SomeClass` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/XHz9Jv

Comment: Correct @stuartd - hence my last sentence in the comment. Hopefully the duplicate link will help the OP understand what `SomeReadonlyPropertyHashSetOfStrings = { "somevalue", "somevalue2"}` is doing under the covers.

Comment: As the [Collection Initializer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) say _"Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection type that implements IEnumerable **and has Add with the appropriate signature as an instance method or an extension method.**"_ - which is why your examples work - the `private set` is irrelevant, as the initializer calls `Add` for each value.

Comment: @mjwills here's what doesn't work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9eqVc4  I need it to or some variation of that because I have to build up what will be in the HashSet. The docs don't cover this. It must be possible. In other languages I'd just use {value1, value2, ... array1} but C# doesn't have that as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @JamesHancock You will need to call `Add` on the hashset to add entries (or write your own `AddRange` so you can add in bulk rather than one at a time).